# How to toggle style property using UseState

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

In react I would like to lock scroll-bar when sub-menu is out and then again unlock it when menu is hidden. I press the same button to open and close sub-menu (adds and removes translate for this element).
With what i did page sucessfully locks but when i press menu button and sub-menu dissapears the page is still locked, how can i change that the code is below:

```
const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
const toggleClass = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"
  };

 <div className="button"
   onClick={toggleClass}
   className={
   isActive ? "nav-button closebtn active" : "nav-button closebtn"}>
   <span></span>
 </div>
```

how can I toggle the value of `overflow` from hidden to unset by pressing the button, just like i do with adding the class when i press the same button

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggle` and add style in CSS file.

```js
import './myStyle.css';
const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
const toggleClass = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
    document.body.classList.toggle('lock', isActive); // <-- Add this
  };

 <div className="button"
   onClick={toggleClass}
   className={
   isActive ? "nav-button closebtn active" : "nav-button closebtn"}>
   <span></span>
 </div>
```

// **myStyle.css**

```cs
.lock {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thank you, actually had to add it like this: ```document.body.classList.toggle('lock', setActive(!isActive))```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in your togle you have to validate if it is active or not and in that change the hidden to visible

**Something like:**

```
const toggleClass = () => {
    setActive((active) => {
      if(active){
          document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
          return !active;
      }
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
      return !active;
    });
    
};
```